# How to use Relationship Extraction using IBM watson?

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson

I used `watson` `Relationship Extraction` for retrieving Quantity but I don't get how can I retrieve Quantity. There is a function for `node.js` like `relationship_extraction.extract()`. In this function there is key `dataset` and default value is `ie-en-news`. I would like to known about this key and value

Answer (score 0):

I believe that after the service exits beta, (or perhaps even in a future beta release), you will be able to upload your own training dataset that can be customized to produce better results for whatever domain you're working in (medical reports, shakespear, whatever). Then the `dataset` option will allow you to use that when performing a relationship extraction.

Currently, however, the only  datasets available are English and Spanish news.